# Im able to add users to sharepoint 2013 but not the groups

Tags: 2013

I'm able to add users to SharePoint 2013 but not the groups. This is a security group.. the same group we are using for sp 2010. issue is only with my new server farm 2013.. even people picker able to recognize the group name and not displaying when I try to open that group.. 
the error I'm getting is something went wrong.

Please Help me to overcome from this Issue..

Thanks & Regards,
Anudeep

Answer (score 1):

You can use a group in active directory and named it : for example : mega-group1 and grant membership to all other groups nested in other group.(in that OU) , then use this new group for permissioning  in SharePoint.

I guess a big and complex mistake, force you to write this question

If your mega-group1 and users make any problems for you , and security or permission modifications apply late or doesn't immediately appears for your users, you should try

1. change the value of WindowsTokenLifetime by this [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/103376/5170)
2. try this:right click on OU and grant delegation (read users info) for service account that run application pools in IIS for your SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint does not do groups in groups as it can not expand the members in (sub)groups.

Are you very sure it is a Security Group and not a Distribution Group (List)